# How to import scripts based on the --project on Angular 6+?

Tags: angular

Ok, let's say I have a structure like this:

```
/
- clients
-- client-1
--- _script.ts
-- client-2
--- _script.ts
```

And my angular.json is like this:

```
...
'projects': {
    "client-1": {...},
    "client-2": {...},
}
...
```

Let's say I have the same code, but with different value on variables inside the 2 script.ts files, like:

client-1/script.ts:

```
export const theme = {
  data_url_api: 'https://client-1.com/api',
}
```

client-2/script.ts:

```
export const theme = {
  data_url_api: 'https://client-2.com/api',
}
```

How can I import and call this file, dynamically inside my code, without forcing the 'client path'? Of course, obbeying the `--project=client-1` I use on the `ng serve` or `ng build`.

My desire would be to import it like this, lets say again, inside a 'data.service.ts':

```
import { theme } from 'script';
```

And the Angular itself would deal with 'which one to import'.

So, is there a way?

Comment: If you really want to do this at build time, you could use the [environment files](https://angular.io/guide/build). This would require a separate build per client.

Comment: I thought about that, @peinearydevelopment, but I can't, because even the environment files you load using abolute paths.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I meant to put your const values in the environment file. Then when your build runs, it switches out the values in the environment file with the ones appropriate for the environment you are building. Then you only need to point to the environment file. Look at your main.ts file for an example. That gets the production values when built with the production environment flag.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment can you detail it more as an Answer, please?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I understand what ou are saying, but I'm not just dealing with different environments, but with different projects on the same workplace too. I can't just use the same environment.ts when I'm on dev mode and different environment.prod.ts files for the 2 projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two projects, this would be a "shared" service/component/file...

Therefore i would tag it as such (for example by putting that file in a specific shared folder)
That will help you (and your co workers) to remember, that every change to this file may have effects on MULTIPLE projects.

For importing i use the "paths" in the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "projects",
    "paths": {
      "@project1/*": [
        "myFirstProject/src/app/*"
      ],
      "@project2/*": [
        "mySecondProject/src/app/*"
      ],
      "@shared/*": [
        "shared/src/*"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

Now i can use

```
import {something} from @shared/myTheme;
```

from everywhere

warm regards

#### EDIT:

My fault,  wrong solution :-)

If it´s the same service,but different endpoints, i use an environment variable to change it.
And in the angular.json i overwrite the generic environment.ts with the project specific  environment.ts

```
 ...
 "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/myFirstProject/src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
...
}
```

I have an environment-file per project and per staging (2 Projects with 3 stages => 6 environment files)

With that i am able to change things globaly per application and depending on the staging environment.

Sorry for the the misunderstanding

warm regards

#### SECOND EDIT

Before it makes problems.
If you replace files depending on a configuration, you should modify not only the "build" part, but also the "serve" part, so that your environment will also be used when using `ng serve`

```
"projects": {
    "myFirstProject": {
      "root": "projects/myFirstProject/",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/myFirstProject/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
             ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/myFirstProject/src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "proxy": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/myFirstProject/src/environments/environment.proxy.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/myFirstProject/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myFirstProject:build:dev"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "myFirstProject:build:dev"
            },
            "proxy": {
              "browserTarget": "myFirstProject:build:proxy"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myFirstProject:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's the point, the script.ts is not shared, it has different content for each project. Like a endpoint. But the service itself is the same, and needs to be able to load the proper endpoint for each project.

Comment: Ups, i am sorry, my fault. For that problem i am using a environment variable. I added my solution to my (wrong) anwser.

Comment: So, the solution would be to have a final 'environment' file for each 'client' and on my dev environment to update the endpoint according to the client im using in realtime? Does the 'dev' configuration actually works? Good to know :)

Comment: Yup, thats a 1to1 copy out of one of my projects. Be aware, the path depends on the postion of the angular.json, not the project root and not the project sourceroot.  I added a detail in my anwser because you have to change your "serve" config also.